# Use apply(,2,) to perform mixed effects(lme()) over columns of a huge dataset

Tags: r

I'm a novice at this, so I can't determine if this is folly or not.
Basically, I want to do pairwise mixed effects models between all continuous variables in a huge dataset.  The obvious alternative is a simple spearman correlation, but I have my reasons and it would take too long to explain why I want to use mixed effects models.

Data looks something like this:

```
0     X1507.07  XAB1524.33  XAB1624.21  XAB1808.09...(~4000 columns)
1       12         19           12         45
2       15         35           2          25
3       22         23           65         33
4       0          55           23         67
5       12         10           90         94
6       34         22           11         2
...
90      13         8            14         45
```

The goal is pairwise models for all columns.
Here's the problematic part of the script:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dat))
{
ni<-names(dat)[i]
pvalue <- apply(dat, 2, function(x)
    {
formula<-as.formula(paste(ni,"~", x," + Location",sep=""))
model<-do.call("lme", args = list(formula, random=~1|Subject, data=dat))    
summary(model)$tTable[2,5]
    })
```

Error:

```
invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

For those confused: I use as.formula because if you try:

```
model<-lme(X1507.07~x+Region,random=~1|Subject, data=dat)
```

Error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

('Location' and 'Subject' are factors in the data frame dat). I only care about the one p value (I know its controversial with mixed effects).  I've tried passing x as.matrix(x) and colnames(x) in the as.formula() but nothing really seems to work.  Point is: Does anyone know if this is even possible?  If I have to loop through it ~10^7 times, its not worth the time (years), so apply() is the only reasonable alternative I can think of.

Comment: `apply` won't be much faster than looping.  `lmer` (from `lme4`) *might* be faster; you can get the t-statistics and translate them to p-values yourself using whatever degrees of freedom you like (including the value that lme would have guessed).  How big is your data set (rows*columns)?  Can you please give a small **reproducible** ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) example?  (PS: it does sound a little bit like folly ... can you give an abbreviated explanation of why you prefer mixed models to correlations? Have you considered http://stats.stackexchange.com ?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I tried lmer as well but ran into similar problems.  This dataset in particular is 92 rows x 3789 columns.  An abbreviated explanation for using mixed effects: 2 similar but distinct biological samples (from two locations in the GI tract) were collected from each subject and I want to get a p value for the relationship between each of the tested parameters that are found in each sample without dividing the dataset by sampled location.  I've already performed correlation analysis and want to use ME as a complement that doesn't require the data to be divided by sample site

Comment: So you really want to do all 3789*3788/2 > 7 million pairwise comparisons?  That's going to be really hard to do in a reasonable amount of time with mixed-effects models, I think.  Can you work out the method-of-moments (i.e. variance decomposition) answer for your particular case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still think this is probably folly, and that you might be able to get a faster solution by working out the method-of-moments answer by hand, but (unless I made a mistake somewhere) the timing of this is not as disastrous as I thought it might be.

**tl;dr** the whole thing should take about 3-4 days by brute force, provided you don't run into any other scaling problems. `lmer` is actually slower (while it was designed to be faster for large problems, the timing on individual small problems may actually be slower because of setup costs). Because `lme` is a non-trivial problem, I think the looping is actually a small part of the total computational cost.

Make up some data:

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 10
nobs <- 90
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rpois(nobs*n,20),nrow=nobs))
Subject <- rep(1:n,each=nobs/n)
Location <- runif(n)
```

Do it with `nlme`:

```
library(nlme)
fun.lme <- function() {
    r <- numeric(n*(n-1)/2)
    k <- 1
    for (i in 2:n) {
        for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
            m <- lme(y~x+Location,random=~1|Subject,
                     data=data.frame(x=dat[,i],y=dat[,j],
                     Location,Subject))
            tt <- summary(m)$tTable[2,5]
            r[k] <- tt
            k <- k+1
        }
    }
    r
}
t1 <- system.time(r1 <- fun.lme())
detach("package:nlme")
```

(detaching `nlme` before working with `lme4` is a good idea)

```
fun.lmer <- function(...) {
    r <- numeric(n*(n-1)/2)
    k <- 1
    for (i in 2:n) {
        for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
            m <- lmer(y~x+Location+(1|Subject),
                     data=data.frame(x=dat[,i],y=dat[,j],
                     Location,Subject),...)
            tt <- coef(summary(m))[2,2]  
            r[k] <- tt
            k <- k+1
        }
    }
    r
}
```

Test timing with stable `lme4`:

```
library(lme4.0) ## 'stable' version (the same as you get by installing
                ## lme4 from CRAN
t2 <- system.time(r2 <- fun.lmer())
detach("package:lme4.0")
```

Now with development (r-forge) `lme4`, with standard and non-standard optimizer choices:

```
library(lme4)
t3 <- system.time(r3 <- fun.lmer())
t4 <- system.time(r4 <- fun.lmer(optim="bobyqa"))
detach("package:lme4")
```

Check the timings:

```
tvals <- c(lme=t1["elapsed"],lme4.0=t2["elapsed"],
           lme4=t3["elapsed"],lme4_bobyqa=t4["elapsed"])
```

Scale the time we took to the time for the full job:

```
totsecs <- (3789*3788/2)*tvals/(n*(n-1)/2)
totdays <- totsecs/(60*60*24)

round(totdays,1)
##   lme.elapsed   lme4.0.elapsed   lme4.elapsed lme4_bobyqa.elapsed 
##           3.0              4.4            4.1                 3.8
```

You might as well use the t-statistics as the p-values for comparison; as far as I can tell p values will be totally irrelevant except as indicators of the strength of association.

Comment: Wow.  You are a bad ass.  I hadn't even gotten a chance to make a reproducible example of my problem.  Thanks so much!!! This is amazing.